# Is my touch lamp safe?

Tags: grounding

The touch lamps body reads 12 volts and it vibrates when I touch it.

Is the lamp safe?

Comment: [Edit] your post to include, at a minimum, the make/model of the lamp, and how you're measuring the voltage. Any additional details you can provide (what kind of bulb, is it a new fixture or old, is it grounded, is it on a GFCI circuit, etc) will be helpful. The best you'll get with what you've provided will be some random guesses.

Comment: There would need to be _some_ electrical potential in the base for it to function as a touch device. Whether it's safe is both unclear given the information we have and a matter of risk tolerance (opinion).

Comment: See JWH20’s answer most touch lamps are capacitive and do not pose a hazard. however a bad cap can allow the DC control voltage through.  not a hazard under 3x what you have measured. I might try flipping the plug over if not polarized and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: This sounds like it could be Y-capacitor leakage. (You can get the same "buzzing" sensation from a laptop with a metal body, when using it with a non-grounded charger. If that's the cause, I'm told it's harmless.) See: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/wiki/design/power#wiki_buzzing_or_tingling_feeling_when_touching_a_metal_case

Answer (score 2):

If the plug is non-polarized (i.e. both blades are the same size) try reversing it in the outlet.

Comment: This is the most probable answer and should not have been down voted but there are a lot of internet only electricians that don’t realize how things work! +